# Django query create __mycondition same __startswish

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset

I have 2 shorts questions related with query in Django:

- What's the name of that ('__startswith' '__lt' ...)
- How I can create '__mycondition' for query

```py
data.exclude(name__startswith="example")
```

if you have examples I would like

Thanks you :)

Comment: `__startswith` is built in with django. I don't think you can do anything similar like your condition. And, what your condition might be, there must be another way rather than having custom.

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane i whant to create condition if variable in object is beetwin 2 date

Comment: What are those 2 dates?

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane it is two dates (start_at, end_at) are in the obect in question model: start_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    end_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now) and i whant solution to do that : data.exclude(if (datetime.now() > start_at && datetime.now() < end_at)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__gt` and `__lt` to work with date. Try:

```
from django.utils import timezone

queryset = data.exclude(start_at__lt=timezone.now(), end_at__gt=timezone.now())
```

[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude)

Comment: i have try but dont work: acctualy i have ended device work with that :                            if dis_ended:
                print("exclude ended device")
                data = data.exclude(end_at__lt=datetime.now())
            if dis_currently:
                print("exclude current device")
                data.exclude(start_at__lt=datetime.now(), end_at__gt=datetime.now())